# Connection establishment between ASP.NET and SQL Server by ADO.Net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I am using ASP.NET web form application and use ado.net to establish connection between SQL Server and my application to perform CRUD operation. I'd like to know: is any socket used to establish the connection like connection between server and client socket?

Actually I want a know how Ado.net establishes a connection with SQL Server to fetch data. I'd like to know what happens internally. Does Ado.net have any client socket part which connects to a server socket at the SQL Server database?

There is any documentation or article on the web to explain how ADO.net handshakes with SQL Server?

Thanks

Comment: @MisterPositive Sir I did didnt get much help

Comment: How you can mark negative to my question if you don't know any anser

Comment: I will report this to stack over flow admin to validate whether is a valid or unavalid question

Comment: This is not a how to use the site.  You should show your efforts ( code ), a specific section of code your having trouble with, and expected out put.

Comment: Because its a bad question. Read the link provided by MisterPositive. What you are asking for is a tutorial on how to interact with a sql server database from an asp.net web application (this in itself is **very** broad). Someone would have to guess as to how you would use your database and then write a complete tutorial, that's very unrealistic. Use Google and find a tutorial, try it with your own code, and then ask a question if you get stuck with the specifics. If this is not what you were asking you need to update the question with only specific details on what it is you want to know.

Comment: @Igor , I will leave programming if you can post a tutorial from google or otherwise don't support MisterPositive, there are thousands question on this website where user post links

Comment: Sherry MisterPositive is not spamming anything. Your question is extremely vague and ambiguous. The answer by Ross Bush was an excellent guess since apparently it answered your question. You seem very frustrated which is understandable. But look at your question and ask yourself if you would be able to answer it. Most people want to see code but we can't even begin to help you with code because it isn't clear what you want.

Comment: You guys even don't read my question properly I know how to do it just want see how internal mechanism work.

Comment: So ask a detailed question about what you want to understand. A vague question is going to elicit people saying you need to ask a question. I suspect part of the problem is that english is not your native tongue which makes it more difficult to be precise. Especially in this case you should provide more details in your question so others have a chance at understanding what you want. But a short question followed by berating people for asking for clarity is not going to work out too well.

Comment: You can find out yourself if it is a valid question in the help center, in which case it is not. Link only answers are off-topic as well. If you don't like the rules we have, then ask on another site

Comment: @ techydesigner you are not the owner of this website so its better not to take the place of admin or route people to other website.

Answer (score 0):

That ADO.NET library wraps the [OLEDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452(v=vs.71).aspx) library which is at a lower layer and in turn encapsulates a lower level native C library called the [ODBC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710252(v=vs.85).aspx). The ODBC opens a socket to the pre-defined SQL Server IP and Port to relays command using SQL Server's native  [TDS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191220(v=sql.105).aspx) message format.

Comment: Thanks Sir for help @Ross Bush